# jQuery selector as variable. Cannot select proper element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This selector works:

```
$('#nav ul li li').append('<span></span>');
```

Then, I have assigned `#nav` to the `$mainNav` and I wrote

`$mainNav.children("ul").children("li").children("li").append('<span></span>');`

**But this doesn't work.**
`console.log($mainNav)` outputs `Object[nav#nav]`.

Comment: append it to the DOM to see the HTML result. Otherwise do a`console.log($mainNav.html())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
$mainNav.find('ul li li').append('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$mainNav` needs to be a jQuery object. If not, you can't use the jQuery API.

```
$mainNav = $($mainNav);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, with your "code" version, is that you have `children("li").children("li")`, but `LI`s are never the direct descendant of another `LI`, so `$mainNav.children("ul").children("li").children("li")` with never find a match.

You could add the missing level:

```
$mainNav.children("ul").children("li").children("ul").children("li").append('<span></span>');
```

Or convert it to a single selector using child `>` selectors:

```
$mainNav.find('ul > li > ul > li').append('<span></span>');
```

You can just do it the way you have solved it (`$mainNav.find('ul li li')`) but that is the same as:

```
$mainNav.find("ul").find("li").find("li").append('<span></span>');
```

which as you can imagine is *a little* slower.